# How to find shortest path in C language

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am working on project that required to make a map first for any country having many cities and then user will be asked to choose any two cities and the program will highlight the shortest path between them.

I want to know how to find shortest path. For example, I have 4 cities A,B,C and D. From City A to City D is 20 it is connected directly. Also, there is another path from City A to City D but this path is shortest if City A go from A --> C --> D.

I want the algorithm to find like previous examples. Also, is Dijkstra Algorithm can help me?

Comment: Use Dijkstra for point-to-point, Floyd-Warshall for all pairs, shortest paths.

Comment: this is a highly complex matter. There are a few algorithms, like Dijkstra, or Floyd-Warshall, but each of them require a lot of computational power. Can you give us some contect and the scale of which you are planning to use this kind of problem?

Comment: My project said "You are required to make a map first for any country having many cities and then user will be asked to choose any two cities and the program will highlight the shortest path between them.

Answer (score 2):

The Floyd–Warshall algorithm is an algorithm for finding shortest paths in a weighted graph. For pairing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Floyd-Warshall C example:
https://github.com/sysilion/ShortestPath/blob/master/src/main.c